# select dropdown "SELECTED" using symfony framework

Tags: php, symfony1, selected

I have been this for many days. My problem is i want to get the data "selected" in the birthdate when i click edit profile, my birthdate input is dropdown select which has year, month and day. My database field is birth_date which has a type date. During when saving the data, the date is saved by this format. for example 1990-01-20, and it will saved, my problem is when i click edit profile the select dropdown has no data, meaning it will not be "selected", how will i able to get the data to be selected? in symfony framework?

Here is my frontend/module/home actions

```
<?php

class editAction extends sfAction{ 
  private function saveData($post, $file=''){
    $firstName = ucfirst($post['first_name']);
    $lastName = ucfirst($post['last_name']);
   // $Slug = $post['slug'];
   // $newSlug = explode(' ', $Slug);
   // $Slug = implode("", $newSlug);
    $cleanFirstName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $firstName);
    $cleanLastName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $lastName);

    $year = $post['year'];
    $month = $post['month'];
    $day = $post['day'];

    $res = $year."-".$month."-".$day;

    $user = Doctrine::getTable('User')->find($post['id']);
    $user->setFirstName($cleanFirstName);
    $user->setLastName($cleanLastName);
    $user->setAbout($post['about']);
    $user->setSex($post['sex']);
    $user->setMobile($post['mobile']);
    $user->setBirthDate($res);
    $user->setSlug($post['slug']);
    $user->save();

    $imageName = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('homeImage');
    if($imageName){
      $temp = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir_150');
      $dir = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir');

      if(is_file($temp.$imageName)){
        $file = $imageName;
        $file['ext'] = getFileExtension($file['name']);

        rename($file.$imageName,$dir.$file);  
        $user->setProfileImage($file);
        $user->save();

      }     
    }else{
      if($file && !$file['error']){
        $file = $this->saveImage($file, $user->getId());
        $user->setProfileImage($file);
        $user->save();
      }
    }

  }

  public function submit($request){
    $user = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('home'.$this->id);
    $imageName = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('homeImage');

    if(!$user){
      return $this->redirect('home/edit?id='.$this->id);
    }
    $this->saveData($user);
    $this->getUser()->setAttribute('home'.$this->id, NULL);
    return $this->redirect('home');

  }

  private function saveImage($file, $id=NULL){
    if(!$id){
      $dir = sfConfig::get('app_company_dir_150');
    }else{
      $dir = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir');
    }

    $medium = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_medium');
    $small = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_small');  
    $dir = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir_150');
    $dir_60 = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir');

    $file['ext'] = getFileExtension($file['name']);

    if(!$id){
      $fileName = uniqid(). '.'.$file['ext'];
    }else{
      $fileName = $id.'.'.$file['ext'];
    }
      $imagePath = $dir.$fileName;

    //saving and cropping image

    $image_medium = encode('home-'.$id).'.'.$fileName;
    $image_small = encode('home-'.$id).'_thumb.'.$fileName;

    $image_medium_path = $dir.$image_medium;
    $image_small_path = $dir_60.$image_small;

    rename($file['tmp_name'],$image_medium_path);

    //cropping image medium
    $image = new myImageManipulator($image_medium_path);
    $image->resample2($medium, $medium);
    $image->crop(0, 0, $medium, $medium);
    $image->save($image_medium_path);

    //cropping image small 
    $image = new myImageManipulator($image_medium_path);
    $image->resample2($small, $small);
    $image->crop(0, 0, $small, $small);
    $image->save($image_small_path);

    if(!$id){
      $this->getUser()->setAttribute('homeImage',$image_medium);    
    }else{
      return $image_medium;     
    }

  }

  private function deleteImageSixty(){
    $dir60 = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir');
    $fileName = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('homeImage');
    if($fileName){
      if(is_file($dir60.$fileName)){
        unlink($dir60.$fileName);
      }
      $this->getUser()->setAttribute('homeImage', '');
    }

  }

  private function deleteImage($fileName){
    $dir = sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir_150');
    $fileName = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('homeImage');
    if($fileName){
      if(is_file($dir.$fileName)){
        unlink($dir.$fileName);
      }
      $this->getUser()->setAttribute('homeImage', '');
    }   
  }

  private function saveImageTmp($request){
    $id = $request->getParameter('id');

    $formName = $this->form->getModelName();
    $file = $this->request->getFiles($formName);
    $file = $file['photo'];

    if($file && $file['error'] == 0){
      #$this->deleteImage();
      #$this->deleteImageSixty();
      $this->saveImage($file);
    }
  }

  public function execute($request){  
    $this->id = $request->getParameter('id');
    if(!$this->id){
      $this->forward404();
    }

    $type = $request->getParameter('type');
    if($type == "submit"){
      return $this->submit($request);
    }

    $this->userLogged = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->find($this->id);
    $this->form = new EditProfileForm($this->userLogged);

    if($request->isMethod('post')){
      $formName = $this->form->getModelName();
      $files = $this->request->getFiles($formName);
      $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($formName),$this->request->getFiles($formName));
      $post = $request->getParameter($formName);

      if($this->form->isValid()){
        $this->saveImageTmp($request);
        $this->getUser()->setAttribute('home'.$this->id, $post);
        return $this->redirect('home/edit?id=' .$this->id. '&type=submit');
      }else{
        $this->saveImageTmp($request);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

in the private function saveData()
this is how i saved the birthdate select dropdown code

```
$year = $post['year'];
    $month = $post['month'];
    $day = $post['day'];


    $res = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
$user->setBirthDate($res);
```

this is my editSuccess code

```
<div class="content" class="wrap">
  <div class="cols marginBottom30 clearFix">
    <div class="content withIcon icon1" style="margin-left:488px; width:500px;">
      <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo url_for('home/edit?id=' .$userLogged->getId());?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(); ?>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $form['first_name']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="error_list">
                <?php echo $form['first_name']->renderError(); ?>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $form['last_name']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="error_list">
                <?php echo $form['last_name']->renderError(); ?>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>  
            <td>
              <?php if($userLogged->getProfileImage()): ?>
              <a href="/uploads/images/<?php echo $userLogged->getProfileImage(); ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/uploads/images/<?php echo $userLogged->getprofileImage(); ?>" /></a>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $form['photo'];?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $form['about']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="error_list">
                <?php echo $form['about']->renderError(); ?>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $form['sex']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="error_list">
                <?php echo $form['sex']->renderError(); ?>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $form['mobile']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <div class="error_list">
                <?php echo $form['mobile']->renderError(); ?>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Year: <?php echo $form['year']; ?>Month: <?php echo $form['month']; ?> Day: <?php echo $form['day']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <div class="error_list">
              <?php echo $form['year']->renderError(); ?>
              <?php echo $form['month']->renderError(); ?>
              <?php echo $form['day']->renderError(); ?>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $form['slug']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <div class="error_list">
                <?php echo $form['slug']->renderError(); ?>
              </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <a href="<?php echo url_for('home'); ?>" title="HomePage">HomePage</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my EditProfileForm.class.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Edit Profile form.
 */
class EditProfileForm extends BaseUserForm{
    public function getModelName(){
      return 'User';
    }

    public function configure(){
      $options = UserTable::getGender();
      $year = UserTable::getInstance()->getYear();
      $month = UserTable::getInstance()->getMonths();
      $day = UserTable::getInstance()->getDays();

      $this->setWidgets(array(
        'id' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
        'first_name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('placeholder'=>'First Name: ')),
        'last_name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('placeholder'=>'Last Name: ')),
        'photo' => new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
            'file_src'    => sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir_150'),
            'is_image'    => true,
            'edit_mode'   => false,
            'with_delete' => false
         )),
        'about' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('placeholder'=>'About Me: ')),
        'sex' => new sfWidgetFormSelectRadio(
          array('choices' => $options)
         ),
        'mobile' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('placeholder'=>'Mobile Number: ')),
        'year' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(
          array('choices'=>$year)
        ),
        'month' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(
          array('choices'=>$month)
        ),
        'day' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(
          array('choices'=>$day)
        ),
        'slug' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('placeholder'=>'Slug: ')),

      ));

      $this->setValidators(array(
        'id' => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(
                array('model' => $this->getModelName(), 
                'column' => 'id', 'required' => false)),
        'first_name' => new sfValidatorString(
            array('trim' => true,'required' => true, 'max_length' => 20),
            array('invalid' => 'required', 'required'=>'Please enter first name', 'max_length' => 'Firstname is too long. 20 characters maximum.')
          ),
         'last_name' => new sfValidatorString(
            array('trim' => true,'required' => true, 'max_length' => 20),
            array('invalid' => 'required', 'required'=>'Please enter last name', 'max_length' => 'Lastname is too long. 20 characters maximum.')
           ),
          'photo' => new sfValidatorFile(array(
              'required'        => false,
              'max_size'        => 500000000000000,
              'mime_types'      => 'web_images',
              'path'            => sfConfig::get('app_GalleryPhoto_dir_150'),
          )),

          'about' => new sfValidatorString(
            array('trim' => true,'required' => true)
           ),

          'sex' => new sfValidatorString(
            array('trim' => true,'required' => true),
            array('required'=>'Please select gender.')
           ),
           'mobile' => new sfValidatorString(
              array('trim' => true,'required' => true, 'max_length' => 20),
              array('invalid' => 'required', 'required'=>'Please enter mobile number', 'max_length' => 'mobile number  is too long. 20 characters maximum.')
           ),
           'year' => new sfValidatorString(
              array('trim' => true),
              array('required'=>'Please enter year.')
           ),
           'month' => new sfValidatorString(
              array('trim' => true),
              array('required'=>'Please select month')
           ),
           'day' => new sfValidatorString(
              array('trim' => true),
              array('required'=>'Please select day')
           ),
           'slug' => new sfValidatorString(
              array('trim' => true,'required' => true),
              array('required'=>'Please enter Slug')
           ),

      ));

        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat($this->getModelName().'[%s]');
        $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback'=>array($this, 'validateForm'))));
    }

    public function validateForm($validator, $values){
      //check slug if special characters has been inputed.
      /*$values = $values['slug'];

      if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$values)){
        $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Invalid Slug Characters.');
        $error_data['slug'] = $error;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
      if(preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '', $values)){
        $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Invalid Slug, At Least No Spaces');
        $error_data['slug'] = $error;
      }*/

      /*if($values['slug']){
        $slug = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->findOneBySlug($values['slug']);
        if($values['slug'] != $slug){
          $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Slug Already Exists.');
          $error_data['slug'] = $error;
        }
      }*/

      if($values['slug']){
        if(!$values['slug']){
           $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Invalid slug.');
           $error_data['slug'] = $error;
        }else{
          if(isset($values['id'])){
            $user = UserTable::getInstance()->checkSlug($values['slug'],$values['id']);
          }else{
            $user = UserTable::getInstance()->findOneBySlug($values['slug']);
          }
          if($user->count()){
            $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Slug is already taken.');
            $error_data['slug'] = $error;
          }
        }
      }

      //check strings if there are special characters.
      if($values['slug']){
        if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$values['slug'])){
          $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Invalid Slug Characters.');
          $error_data['slug'] = $error;
        }
      }

      //check two strings if it has spaces
      if(preg_match('/\s/',$values['slug'])){
        $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Invalid Slug. At Least No Spaces');
        $error_data['slug'] = $error;
      }

      if(isset($error_data)){
        throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, $error_data);
      }
      return $values;

    }
}
```

and this is my UserTableClass.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * UserTable
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 */
class UserTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  /**
     * Returns an instance of this class.
     *
     * @return object UserTable
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        return Doctrine_Core::getTable('User');
    }

    public static function getGender(){
      return array(
        1 => 'Male',
        2 => 'Female'
      );
    }

    public static function getDays(){
      return array(
        '' => '----',
        1 => '1',
        2 => '2',
        3 => '3',
        4 => '4',
        5 => '5',
        6 => '6',
        7 => '7',
        8 => '8',
        9 => '9',
        10 => '10',
        11 => '11',
        12 => '12',
        13 => '13',
        14 => '14',
        15 => '15',
        16 => '16',
        17 => '17',
        18 => '18',
        19 => '19',
        20 => '20',
        21 => '21',
        22 => '22',
        23 => '23',
        24 => '24',
        25 => '25',
        26 => '26',
        27 => '27',
        28 => '28',
        29 => '29',
        30 => '30',
        31 => '31'     
      );
    }

    public static function getMonths(){
      return array(
        '' => '----',
        1 => 'January',
        2 => 'February',
        3 => 'March',
        4 => 'April',
        5 => 'May',
        6 => 'June',
        7 => 'July',
        8 => 'August',
        9 => 'September',
        10 => 'October',
        11 => 'November',
        12 => 'December'       
      );
    }

    public static function getYear(){
      return array(
        '' => '----',
        2014 => '2014',
        2013 => '2013',
        2012 => '2012',
        2011 => '2011',
        2010 => '2010',
        2009 => '2009',
        2008 => '2008',
        2007 => '2007',
        2006 => '2006',
        2005 => '2005',
        2004 => '2004',
        2003 => '2003',
        2002 => '2002',
        2001 => '2001',
        2000 => '2000',
        1999 => '1999',
        1998 => '1998',
        1997 => '1997',
        1996 => '1996',
        1995 => '1995',
        1994 => '1994',
        1993 => '1993',
        1992 => '1992',
        1991 => '1991',
        1990 => '1990',
        1989 => '1989',
        1988 => '1988',
        1987 => '1987',
        1986 => '1986',
        1985 => '1985',
        1984 => '1984',
        1983 => '1983',
        1982 => '1982',
        1981 => '1981',
        1980 => '1980'
      );
    }

    public function checkSlug($slug, $id=NULL){
      $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('User u')
        ->where('u.slug = ?',$slug);

      if($id){
        $q->andWhere('u.id <> ?',$id);
      }

      $q->limit(1);
      return $q->execute();
    }

}
```

And in my UserTable.class.php file in there i put the code public function getDays() getMonths() getYear().

Now when i click edit profile all the data will be displayed, execpt for the birthdate it will not be selected. Can anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your EditProfileForm.php set the birth date bits as defaults for the 3 selects:

```
$bd = $this->getObject()->getBirthDate();
$bits = explode('-', $bd);
$this->setDefault('year', $bits[0]);
$this->setDefault('month', $bits[1]);
$this->setDefault('day', $bit[2]);
```

Comment: thanks for the comments.. i just got the solutions! same solutions to your answer! sorry late read...

Comment: No problem - if that answer is valid though please mark it as so to help others or add your own.